# google app engine app works fine on localhost but URL displays nothing PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Alright after becoming very frustrated, I don't understand why my app is not up. I have it hosted on a website and when I open it on my localhost everything runs great. But when I click to deploy it, there is nothing just a white page at the URL. I don't even know where to start looking for a problem. The Logs are apparently uninteresting. Though I am not completely certain what this means?

```
69.144.176.174 - - [08/May/2015:21:58:36 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 25 -     "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.3.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.3 Safari/600.3.18" "www.thepigflys.com" ms=4 cpu_ms=1 cpm_usd=0.000003 app_engine_release=1.9.20 instance=00c61b117c90740883746d46c9e3c98da627ce15<
```

Does anyone have any hints or help on where to look for issues? 
Here is my app.yaml file for anyone interested.

```
application: never-never-93903
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/(.*)

- url: /
  script: public/index.php

- url: /php/
  script: public/php/send_email.php
```

Everything was running fine until I switched it from an index.html to a index.php. All I wanted to do was add a contact form.

Comment: In the logs, if you click the plus sign there should be some extra detail.

Comment: Try putting the index.php file up a level, in the project root directory and updating your app.yaml file to script:index.php (instead of script:public/index.php ). I'm wondering if the overlapping directory is causing issues.

Comment: Why would putting the index.php up a level do anything? You are correct in that it made it work. Now my app.yaml reads: `- url: /
  script: index.php` But why does this work?

Comment: Hi Andrew -- did my answer help and did the explanation make sense? Let me know if the answer didn't fit your situation or answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the index.php file up a level, in the project root directory and updating your app.yaml file to script:index.php (instead of script:public/index.php ). I'm wondering if the overlapping directory is causing issues.

Your first directive is creating a non-executable directory of files to be served as static pages (rather than processed and the output served). So, the files uploaded for the static handler are not, by default, readable for application execution.

Take a look at the following documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

specifically, the "application_readable" directive. That would be the other option -- to make the entire directory application readable; however, I'd suggest just keeping them in separate directories for better organization.

Of course, you can also move your PHP file(s) into a completely different directory, if you don't want them sitting in your project root for organization purposes.

Comment: Hey Mike this worked! That makes sense now. I feel like not a smart person for missing that!! Thank you!